# Почему сайт ищет по пути который я не прописывал

Tags: html

Картинка у меня в `portfolio/assets/img/картинка`.
Но какой бы путь я не писал, он добавляет в начало `Desktop/portfolio/assets/css/` и мой путь.

Я и весь путь писал все пытался, все равно добавляет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы хотите указать фоновое изображение в вашей таблице стилей? Если файл стилей находится в папке portfolio/assets/css, то укажите путь "../img/изображение".

../ говорит браузеру подняться на уровень выше, относительно текущего файла (в случае таблицы стилей - папки portfolio/assets/css, т.е. в папку portfolio/assets, а оттуда уже идти к файлу img/изображение)